# I keep getting a dimension error where it says it's expecting the input to have 4 dimensions but got shape with (2062,64,64).

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

```
x = np.load('/Users/bharddwajvemulapalli/Documents/tensorFlowProjects/Sign-language-digits-dataset 2/X.npy')
y = np.load('/Users/bharddwajvemulapalli/Documents/tensorFlowProjects/Sign-language-digits-dataset 2/Y.npy')
x = x/255
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation,Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D  #dense means fully connected
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
print(x.shape) # (2062, 64, 64)
BATCH_SIZE = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(6,6), input_shape = (64,64,1))) #figure out this input shape parameter to make this work
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(3,3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1)) #output layer
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer  ='adam' , metrics = ['accuracy'])
#x = np.arange(8445952)
#x= np.reshape(64,64,1)
model.fit(x,y,batch_size = 32, epochs = 2, validation_split  =.1)
```

The above is my code. I thought that keras would automatically attach batch_size to (64,64,1) so that I could get 4 dimensions, because when I add a fourth dimension myself, then I get an error that it wasn't expecting an array of dimension 5.

Answer (score 0):

`x` must be 4-dimensional, where the 4th dimension is the number of channels. Since in your case there is only `1` channel, you can add the channel by

```
if x.ndim == 3:
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)
```

This will add a new dimension at the end.

Comment: Doing that gives me "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_3 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (10,)."